# SQL Server: create clustered Index for a staging table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, indexing

Every night, we get data delivered from foreign systems into a staging table in our Microsoft SQL Server.

Because the data is delivered every night, there is no primary key possible to be defined, since the input comes from other tables from foreign systems.

Restructuring and import of this staging table will be done later on, via SSIS.

The staging table currently does not have a clustered index defined and looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [STA].[BusinessPartner]
(
    [runID] [NVARCHAR](255) NULL,
    [someID] [NVARCHAR](255) NULL,
    [data1] [NVARCHAR](32) NULL,
    [data2] [NVARCHAR](32) NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

`RunID` is every delivery new generated and is a unique identifier, for the delivery and the source sysem. Like "sourceSystem_2019092410" and will be changed for every delivery, so the historical deliveries can be seen for every night.

Each table have the unique identifier from the source table from the source system, like in this example [someID].

Questions:

- Should I create an clustered index on this table?

  I assume yes, because there several sources says, INSERT and BULK INSERT are faster with Index.
- Should I create the clustered index on `[runID]` and on `[someID]`?

  I am not sure, because larger values may impact probably have negative impacts. Sure I will make some performance tests.
- Is the order of the columns important? And if yes, should I use the `RunID` or the `[SomeID]` first?

I hope my example and questions are understandable.

Comment: "because there several sources says, INSERT and BULK INSERT are faster with Index." Either you misread that or you found some very strange sources. Bulk inserting is fastest on a heap table (i.e. no indexes at all), and that also allows parallel bulk inserts. For very large tables that have only a small amount of data added to them, inserting with indexes in place can be faster than dropping and recreating them, but in general, the fewer indexes the better.

Comment: Given link exactly do not give your answer because in given link all Keys are `INT`.Your proposed Keys are `Nvarchar(255)`. So if you create CI on `Nvarchar(255)` field then your performance will get worse from bad.So given link only answer part of your question.So this question is not duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there several sources says, INSERT and BULK INSERT are faster with
>   Index.

Yes you read it correct.As data in `HEAP` table are unsorted.While inserting in `HEAP` table,database engine will search for empty space in each page.Because data can be store any where.So this database search will take time.

In `Clustered Index`, data are stored in sorted manner.Database engine will sort it depending upon what key is chosen for `Clustered Index`.(Short explanation)

So `INSERT` may or may not benefit depending upon `Clustered Key` Column.

So choosing so wide key like `[runID] [NVARCHAR](255) NULL` or
 `someid [runID] [NVARCHAR](255) NULL` may not help.

So I think you should introduce `Identity column` which is `Clustered Index`.
So database engine will always know where to insert new data.Data will inserted always in last page.

> Should I create the clustered index on [runID] and on [someID]?

No. 
 You are right "because larger values may impact probably have negative impacts. Sure I will make some performance tests".Already explained above

If possible, make data length narrower and data type suitable.

So like use `VARCHAR` instead of `nvarchar` .change data length from `255` to `100` or whatever less value possible.

Comment: @christian-müller,  Given link exactly do not give your answer because in given link all Keys are `INT`.Your proposed Keys are `Nvarchar(255)`. So if you create CI on `Nvarchar(255)` field then your performance will get worse from bad.

Comment: Thank you a lot. It is more answer as I asked :) I make performance test and best benefits where going down fron NVARCHAR not only to VARCHAR, but to CHAR at all. And also Clustered Index was bad for performance.

Answer (score 1):

both type of index is for sort the data clustered for real data and non clustered for create balanced tree and reference of data

in both type when you insert some data the tree of index will be update then insert and bulk insert operation run a bit slower than heap table

heap table (a table without any cluster index)

you can use heap table with non clustered index.
for example you can use covered non clustered index for remove key lookup and give performance

but you can use non clustered index for give performance on read data from stage db and you should be careful to use it.

you can use heap table with non clustered index.
for example use non clustered cover index for remove one key lookup and give performance

the row order effect depend on read and insert business from stage db to OLAP data base.

you can get execution plan from your query and check the performance of your query

Comment: Heap tables have their own set of problems, and are generally *not* a good choice when performance is key.

Comment: @marc_s if you want to use heap table as main database table i agree with you but its good for use on the stage db. can you explain heap table problem? please

Comment: See e.g. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/sql-server-heaps-and-their-fragmentation/ , https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/heaps-tables-without-primary-key-clustered-index/ , http://kejser.org/clustered-indexes-vs-heaps/ and many more

Comment: Thank you marc_s: In the blitz Artikel "Good Reasons To Use A Heap", answers a lot of my questions (and questions I not asked, like should I insert a primary key as Identity).

Comment: @ChristianMüller if your primary key is a incremental key its good. but if your read business from stage db dont use  of this index its extra column and key. as a rule we use one none cluster index for performance if non clustered index column is incremental value thats better choice. the column of this non clustered index choose base on read business from stage db

Comment: Yes. I understand this now and with the article. I am now make performance test, without cluster index and without primary key.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience the most important thing to consider when deciding if you want to put an index on a staging table is what you're going to do with the data afterwards.

Look at subsequent operations and in particular update and/or merge statements. How the staging data is joined in these? If there's an advantage to adding indexes then it will most likely be from picking an index that speeds these steps up by matching the join and any filters applied. Only direct testing will give you an idea of how much difference and whether it's best to add the index before loading the data or after.

You may also wish to consider:

- Uniqueness - Particularly with merge statements there can be a significant performance boost if you explicitly declare the index to be unique so do so it you can.
- Compression - Page compression tends to not be worth it for the one time trip data takes in a staging table but given you're using nvarchar data types row compression might reduce the storage footprint of your data which will in turn reduce the need for I\O throughput. This can often make a big impact on performance.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that create any indexes on staging tables is a good idea. In case you don't do any operations with the table like update, delete etc  with some filters.
A good way:
 - have some historical table;
 - delete data in staged table;
 - create\redesign your current solution according to  your business needs and rules